# Is it possible to execute a PHP script and include the result in another one before result is served?

Tags: php, apache, http, client-server

I have a php script http://example.com/myapp/myscript.php running on an Apache server. I call this URL from a mobile app, the script does its logic, then set HTTP headers and body with data as a JSON string ( that the mobile app later parses and handles ).
Now I would like to have an URL http://example/myapp/mypage.php that would retrieve the data returned by myscript.php, lay it out with html and serve the page.
I achieve the result by first serving the page empty, myscript.php is then called via Ajax and the layout is done client-side with the Ajax response, but I wonder if it is possible to do this in only one http request :
1/ call mypage.php that would call and execute myscript.php on the server side
2/ retrieve the JSON data in mypage.php, parse it and lay it out on the server side
3/ serve the page

PHP include does not work, as it would just include the code, without executing it first.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to go PHP -> JSON -> PHP -> HTML? If you are on the same server, why not save yourself two steps and just go PHP -> HTML?

Comment: Is there a problem with running the routines in myscript in the same file that renders the final output?  Is it a time-consumptive routine that would have an intolerable delay when running?  Perhaps you mean something like sending a CURL request with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the question, but why can't you just require() the .php file you need, then call a function in it?

```
<?php
require('myscript.php');
$foo = myscript_class::function();
?>
```

Comment: Really, this is the only sane answer. Anything else is just sloppy programming. You have some code that you want to reuse on 2 pages .. that's what functions are for.

Comment: I wanted to avoid to have to re-write the initial scripts that did not include any class ( they were just setting the response header and body ), but I will follow your recommendation and make it cleaner.

Comment: Read up on the model-view-controller design pattern.  It really makes a lot of sense in PHP, especially when you will have views on different devices/platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You could rig something with the output buffers. Something like this:

```
ob_start();
//do your code
$_SESSION['page_buffer'] = ob_get_clean();
```

Then read that session variable in the next page.

That said, why wouldn't you just call `mypage` directly, and have it `include("myscript.php");`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the question, but if what you want is to get the JSON output of that page, you could `file_get_contents()` the page (use the URL, not the path) and then parse it with PHP. Alternatively, you could include() the page using an output buffer, saving the JSON in a variable.

```
ob_start();
include 'file.php';
$output = json_decode(ob_get_clean(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP include should work. It executes the code in a PHP file if you include it.

Check this URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Check example 5: it returns the value instead of the code.